# R implementation of kohonen SOMs: prediction error due to data type.

Tags: r, som

I have been trying to run an example code for supervised kohonen SOMs from https://clarkdatalabs.github.io/soms/SOM_NBA . When I tried to predict test set data I got the following error:

```
pos.prediction <- predict(NBA.SOM3, newdata = NBA.testing)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
Data type not allowed: should be a matrix or a factor
```

I tried newdata = as.matrix(NBA.testing) but it did not help. Neither did as.factor().

Why does it happen? And how can I fix that?

Comment: can you show the `class(NBA.testing)`? And repeat that once you've converted to a matrix/factor to check that it has transformed correctly?

Comment: @RAB > class(NBA.testing)
[1] "matrix"
 class( as.matrix(NBA.testing))
[1] "matrix"
> typeof( as.matrix(NBA.testing))
[1] "double"

Comment: hmm, why is it a double in the last example...maybe thats the issue?

Comment: @RAB it is double because I used typeof() to provide additional information on data type. Double means the same as numeric and it should be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

You should put one more argument to the predict function, i.e. "whatmap", then set its value to 1.
The code would be like:

```
pos.prediction <- predict(NBA.SOM3, newdata = NBA.testing, whatmap = 1)
```

To verify the prediction result, you can check using:

```
table(NBA$Pos[-training_indices], pos.prediction$predictions[[2]], useNA = 'always')
```

The result may be different from that of the tutorial, since it did not declare the use of set.seed() function.
I suggest that the set.seed() with an arbitrary number in it was declared somewhere before the training phase.
For simplicity, put it once on the top most of your script, e.g.

```
set.seed(12345)
```

This will guarantee a reproducible result of your model next time you re-run your script.

Hope that will help.